# Ruby: How to loop the fetch call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, date

I am trying to compare dates but is in an array and the way I figured out to get the dates out of the way is using the `.fetch` call. 
So, currently the code is `Activity.pluck(:start_date).fetch(1)` but I want to call the fetch function and for all.

Does anyone know of a method that will return each values in an array to a Date?

Comment: Show the migration or `schema.rb` for your current model, if you think it should have a member `start_date`...

Comment: Show full controller action code.

Answer (score 1):

`Date.parse(:start_date)` is passing a symbol; that caused the error. Would `Date.parse(start_date)` work?

Comment: When I tried that it have `undefined local variable or method `start_date' for #<ActivitiesController:0x007fa5ae201768>`. So I added `@activity_events.start_date` (which is the name of the table in the controller) and I got this `undefined method `start_date' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear - you're calling `start_date` on `self`, which in this scope is the `ActivitiesController` class. This method isn't defined in this class so it's raising an error. If you have an ActiveRecord instance object of type `Activity` that responds to this message, then call it on that instead. The only way this code would work is if you have a method `start_date` within this controller that returns a string representation of a date/time.

If you are calling it on such an object (Activity), but it's still not working, then in all likelihood your `activities` table is missing a `start_date` datetime column. If it doesn't, add the column (can use the rails generator to create the migration)

In your rails root directory:
`bundle exec rails g migration add_start_date_to_activities start_date:datetime`
then run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and you should be good to go

Comment: It seems to you're missing a fundamental concept here:

`Activity` is a class. What you're talking about doing requires an instance of this class (which will be an `ActiveRecord` object).

At the moment you're calling the `start_date` method on the class itself, when you should be calling it on an instance of the class, e.g. `activity = Activity.new(start_date: Date.today)` ...then you can do `activity.start_date` to access this property of the object.

Answer (score 0):

From your first attempt it is clear that "self" is not an active record. use your active record object to get 'start_date'.

```
@record.start_date
```

Comment: Hmm, here is the problem, as you can see @activity_events  is an active record of model named 'Class'. You should try with an active record of model "Activity"

Comment: Try by.
'Activity.first.start_date'

What is the o/p